# Can we perform load/stress tesing using new relic tool?

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing, newrelic

We have a requirement to perform stress testing on website for 1000 concurrent users. Is it possible using new relic (without use of jmeter)?

Comment: Any specific reason to use relic? What are your exact requirements?

Comment: Isn't New Relic a server-side monitoring and analysis tool?  It's not a load testing tool, AFAIK.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm whether it is possible to perform load testing using new relic. Requirement is  to perform load testing on website for 1000 users at the time of login. Basically I wanted to know the bottleneck code in website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Relic is a tool for monitoring applications (on the server and the end-user experience), transactions, and servers. You could use it to measure the effects of a large load, but it doesn't apply the load.

You could use something like [Blitz](https://www.blitz.io/), [SOASTA](http://www.soasta.com/), [Cloud Assault](https://www.cloudassault.com/), or [BlazeMeter](http://blazemeter.com/) to apply load and run tests.

Comment: Hi rkb, does it tell you information like the number of users etc? How do concurrent users impact new relic?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. But if you have 1000 users i think you must use any hosting which provides cloud servers. I used  Blazemeter and after testing i had very good reporting. I used their tutorial  about [new relic plugin](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/214577-blazemeter-plugin-for-new-relic)